# What's the difference between $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess'...) and calling a method in the scope function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm starting with AngularJS and I have a question related to the way a method is invoked when setting a new controller.

Let's say I have a route configured like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/myApp/:id', {controller: 'MyAppCtrl'});
```

- What's the difference between these 2 controller codes, regarding the execution context and the $scope life cycle?
- How many times each alternative runs after the partial is loaded?

.

```
app.controller('MyAppCtrl',function($scope,$routeParams){
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
        $scope.data = getNewData($routeParams.id);
    });
    function getNewData(id){
        ...
    }
});
```

And:

```
app.controller('MyAppCtrl',function($scope,$routeParams){
    $scope.data = getNewData($routeParams.id);

    function getNewData(id){
        ...
    }
});
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, I would use resolve in route config instead of your 2 options

back to your question.

I believe controller only execute once after the partial is loaded.

and these 2 cases are pretty much doing the same thing. The first one relies on event, which is an extra step comparing with the 2nd one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've just learned about the resolve, which clarifies my inquiry. Both responses answer my question, but I'm marking this as the answer because it gives a little more help with the use of resolve in the route configuration, and that solves my issue. Thanks again to @msohns and maxisam.

Answer (score 0):

$on assigns a listener to an event. Meaning You could trigger $on manually by sending $broadcast('routeChangeSucess').

The second code is run one time, once The partial is loaded.

So using $on for a Controller load dosn't do You any good